# Can I reenter Brazil as a tourist after a work visa expires?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, brazil, working-visas

Can I enter into Brazil as a tourist, after a work visa expires?

Comment: Which country are you a citizen of?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

I spent a long time researching this and I wasn't able to find a definite source, but I did this without any problem.

I left Brazil on the last day of my work visa (VITEM V) and I entered a month later and I received a 90 days tourist visa on arrival.